# angularjs and react property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, reactjs

I have Problem implementing Reactjs 0.13.1 in angularJS customs directive when I call MYCOMPONENT mixin and pass it to react I have this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined
    at ReactClass.createClass.Constructor (react-with-addons-0.13.1.js:6237)
    at Object.fn (ReceptionReactController.js:21)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14243)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14506)
    at done (angular.js:9659)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9849)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9790)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11607$get @ angular.js:8557$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:14261$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:14506done @ angular.js:9659completeRequest @ angular.js:9849requestLoaded @ angular.js:9790
```

I don't know why the __reactAutoBindMap is undefined  inside react constructor?

MYCOMPONENT.js

```
var MYCOMPONENT = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'MYCOMPONENT',
    render: function () {
        return React.DOM.div(null, "Rendering faster in AngularJs with ", this.props.framework);

    }
});
```

angular view

```
<body >
    <h1>Faster Rendering With ReactJs</h1>
    <div >
        <input ng-model="framework" />
        <hr>
        <fast-ng framework="framework"></fast-ng>
    </div>
</body>
```

controller and directive

```
/** @jsx React.DOM*/
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('App');

    var ReceptionReactController = function ($scope){
        $scope.framework = 'test';

    };

    app.controller('ReceptionReactController', ['$scope', ReceptionReactController]).directive('fastNg', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                framework: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs){
                scope.$watch('framework', function(newValue, oldValue){
                    React.render(
                        MYCOMPONENT({ framework: newValue }),
                        el[0]
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    });

}());
```

[image]

I have fork plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UMfKatketZadKVnvlfJV?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using angular I prefer to use render and passing a component I created inside, as follow: -

```
React.render(React.createElement(
      MYCOMPONENT,{
        framework: newValue
      }),
      el[0]
    );
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Aq4zED2DFB9T69KHMcEV?p=preview